# Handle login using Google Authentication in system with client and server running on different port reactJS and nodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, google-signin

Currently I'm working in proj using different port at client and server. I'm confusing about handling event in Client whenever login successful in Server. I don't know how to process to login at Client too. I'm using PassPortJS.
I added a button to handle onClick event in client, than start calling server to Authentication with Google by:

```
let gg_window = window.open("http://localhost:7000/authentication/google/auth", "_self");
```

I also config my google app for Authentication as below (Client running on port 9000, server in port 7000)
[Google Authentication configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWOBd.png)

**In Server:**
I made an endpoint to handle URL as:

```
router.get('/google/auth', 
  passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope:
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
  })
);

router.get('/google/auth/redirect',
  passport.authenticate('google'),
  (req, res) => {
    const token = jwt.sign(JSON.stringify(req.user), SECRET);
    res.redirect("http://localhost:9000/google/auth/success?username=" + req.user.username + "&token=" + token);
  });
```

I can get token, username... and redirect to client is ok
**In Client**
I'm using Redux-Saga, normal login with username and password is implemented before.
What should I do now? Thanks for any helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd implemented this feature by this way:

**In Client:**

Made an component to handle end-point "/google/auth/success" as:

```
  <Route
    component={ConfirmAccount}
    path="/google/auth/success"
  />
```

In ConfirmAccountView, I've made a view to confirm UserName which inputted by user. Then have a button to confirm Account.

I made useEffect() of Hook to handle this View and save data to localStorage like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn === true) {
      localStorage.setItem("authorize_token", authorization_token)
      localStorage.setItem("user", username)
      history.push('/profile')
    }
    if (error) {
      NotificationManager.error(`${error}`, "Login Failed")
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem("authorize_token")) {
      history.push('/profile')
    }

  }, [isLoggedIn, error]);
```

I also made a connect function to get state and post action to reducer:

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn(),
  authorization: authorization(),
  error: displayError()
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    loginSuccessWithGG: username => {
      dispatch(loginSuccessWithGG(username)); // Action dispatch for signin
    }
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConfirmAccount);
```

In Redux-Saga, I made an action to dispatch action SignInSuccessful to reducer, then Reducer will set state isLoggedIn to True.
It's worked now.